# How to create a right facing arrow (chevron) using XML shapes in android?

Tags: android, xml, android-drawable, shapes

How to create a right facing arrow using xml shapes in android like this??[image]

Comment: you can't do it with xml drawables, you could try this: https://github.com/pskink/PathDrawable

Comment: @pskink if we can rotate a square at an angle then i think we can do it..any idea about this.??

Answer (score 63, accepted):

I've had a similar problem. Here's how I solved it:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item>
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent"/>
            <size android:width="2dp" android:height="50dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:bottom="20dp">
        <rotate
            android:fromDegrees="-45"
            android:toDegrees="45">
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <solid android:color="@android:color/black"/>
                <corners
                    android:radius="1dp"
                    android:bottomRightRadius="0dp"
                    android:bottomLeftRadius="0dp"/>
            </shape>
        </rotate>
    </item>

    <item android:top="20dp">
        <rotate
            android:fromDegrees="45"
            android:toDegrees="45">
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <solid android:color="@android:color/black"/>
                <corners
                    android:radius="1dp"
                    android:topRightRadius="0dp"
                    android:topLeftRadius="0dp"/>
            </shape>
        </rotate>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

The first item is an empty shape to expand the drawable. Then, I've used 2 rectangles. Each of them has 2 sides rounded.

You need to use this drawable via an `ImageView`:

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:src="@drawable/arrow"
    android:contentDescription="@string/arrow_descriptor"/>
```

Here's the result:

[image: arrow example]

**Note:** AndroidStudio doesn't render different corner sizes, but it shows up properly on devices.

Comment: how I can make up facing arrow using xml ? Please help me.

Comment: @GanpatKaliya attribute on the `ImageView`: android:rotate="-90"

Answer (score 67):

No need to write your own XML, there's a standard Material design chevron.

In Android Studio, click on the `res` folder -> `New` -> `Vector Asset`, then click the icon (button with Android logo) and search for "Arrow".

Select the arrow you want, it will be added to your project. You can open the XML file and edit the dimensions and color if needed.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is the best answer now. It answers the intent of the question rather than the exact question which we need more of on this website.

Comment: But this creates some padding around image.. Is there any way to avoid that?

Comment: Vector Asset is no longer accessible from File->New. Right click on the `res` folder -> `New` leads to the dialog shown in the answer

Answer (score 5):

<strike>It is not possible to create such shape using drawable xml only</strike>( [See answer by user3249477](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28925593/958897) ), if you want to create such shape programmatically, either you create a custom drawable or view. Here, is the code for right side arrow shape. ( Colour and diameter can be configured in xml using styleable )

```
package com.kiriyard.stackoverflow24723040.views;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.graphics.Path.Direction;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;

public class ArrowView extends View {



    private Paint arrowPaint;
    private Path arrowPath;
    private int arrowColor = 0xFF888888;
    private float density;
    private int diameter = 25, diameter_calc, radius_calc;

    public ArrowView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        stuff();
    }

    public ArrowView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        stuff();
    }

    public ArrowView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        stuff();
    }

    private void stuff() {

        //Getting density "dp"
        density = getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().scaledDensity;
        //Calculating actual diameter
        diameter_calc = (int) density * diameter;
        radius_calc = diameter/2;

        //Creating paint
        arrowPaint = new Paint();
        arrowPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        arrowPaint.setColor(arrowColor);

        //Initialize path
        arrowPath = new Path();

        this.setWillNotDraw(false);
    }

    private int startX,startY, currentX, currentY;

    protected void onDraw(Canvas c) {

        startX = c.getWidth();
        startY = c.getHeight()/2;

        c.rotate(-45, startX, startY);

        arrowPath.reset();
        currentX = startX;
        currentY = startY;
        //Move to right end side center of the canvas
        arrowPath.moveTo(currentX,currentY);
        //Lets move up
        currentY = radius_calc;
        arrowPath.lineTo(currentX, currentY);
        //Now draw circle
        currentX-=radius_calc;
        arrowPath.addCircle(currentX, radius_calc, radius_calc, Direction.CCW);
        currentX-=radius_calc;

        arrowPath.lineTo(currentX,currentY);
        // Go to inner side center point
        currentX = startX - diameter_calc;
        currentY = startY - diameter_calc;
        arrowPath.lineTo(currentX,currentY);
        // Go left
        currentX = startX - startY + radius_calc;
        arrowPath.lineTo(currentX, currentY);       
        //Draw circle
        currentY+=radius_calc;
        c.drawCircle(currentX, currentY, radius_calc, arrowPaint);
        currentY+=radius_calc;
        arrowPath.lineTo(currentX, currentY);
        //Go to start
        arrowPath.lineTo(startX, startY);

        c.drawPath(arrowPath, arrowPaint);
    }

}
```

Screenshot

[image: Arrow Screenshot]

So this is one of the way ! ... .. drawable image is easier way.