# XML drawable not showing up correctly on ImageView

Tags: android

I have been trying to get an XML drawable to be a background on a button but it doesn't render correctly. I've gone up the chain all the way to ImageView and it still doesn't render correctly.

I have the xml drawable code from here: [How to create a right facing arrow using xml shapes in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24723040/how-to-create-a-right-facing-arrow-using-xml-shapes-in-android)

Instantiating and setting the background:

```
 rightArrow = new ImageView(context);
 rightArrow.setImageResource(R.drawable.arrow_right);
```

Adding the ImageView to the parent view:

```
 arrowLayout.addView(rightArrow);
```

But the "arrow" is only partially rendered (as seen here):
[layout.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cb316.png)

The LinearLayout containing everything has a cyan background to see it better. After the TextView should be an ImageView of the arrow but its not rendered correctly.

**EDIT**: 
    arrowLayout relavant code:

```
RelativeLayout arrowLayout;
arrowLayout = new RelativeLayout(context);
arrowLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);

arrowLayout.addView(rightArrow);
layout.addView(arrowLayout);
```

Comment: Some problems with arrowLayout. Please post the relevant code.

Comment: you want to add an arrow to the button, Right?

Comment: Yes i want to add an arrow to the button. Specified as an XML drawable